# Lightning Components work differently in Developer orgs and production orgs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, lightning

I have developed several lightning components, which can be accessed in salesforce1 by tab. With the same code, my components work well in DEV orgs, but not in Production Orgs.

For exemple : 
1.  I need to pass parameter object like this:

```
{“Name”:”MyName”,
 “Color”:”Red”,
 “Location”:[{“level1”:”first Level”}, 
             {“level2”:”second Level”}, 
             {“level3”:”third Level”},  
            ]
}
```

by aura:event from one component to another. In dev orgs, I can pass the parameter by event correctly, but in Production Orgs, the Location Array inside the parameter object is lost(undefined) in event receive component.
2.  In a component helper, I have a function like this :

```
getAccountinQueue : function(component) {
    …
    if (component.elements) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

I can always have the “component” information correctly in dev orgs, but in production orgs, the component.elements is undefined even though my current component is still exists.

I have lots of small bugs like this (mainly JavaScript code behaves differently), which are not exist in DEV orgs but exists in Production. I am wondering if I need to configure something to make the lightning components behave in the same way in both dev and production orgs?

By the way, My domain is active in both organization.

Comment: is Lightning locker service disabled in one org and enabled in another>

Comment: Hey Pranay, Thank you for replying. In my dev orgs, the service locker is not actived.

Comment: Hey Pranay, Thank you for replying. In dev orgs, the service locker is not active. In production org, I did not activated it manually, could you please tell me how to check if is the LockerService is active for Lightning Components(Not Lightning LockerService Security for Communities) ?

Comment: You can check the critical update section. You will find Locker services acivated